# how to convert float to hex array

Tags: c

I want to convert a float value to a hex array. Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{

    int8_t float_data[4] = { 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };

    float f_value = 12.59;

    *(float_data) = f_value;

    int i = 0;

    while (i != 4)
        printf("%x", float_data[i++]);

}
```

I want to insert my float value into float_data as 4 bytes of hex values. How can I do this?

Comment: Indentation/formatting.............

Comment: C or C++? C++ way may be like this: `*reinterpret_cast<float*>(float_data) = f_value;` ?

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: Do not spam tags: pick one of language tagged

Comment: What you probably want is `*((float *)(float_data)) = f_value;`.... but take note that it will break strict aliasing rule

Comment: Why do you want to do that, if you want to send float value to other application, its better convert it to ascii string "12.59" rather than sending binary as floating point representation may differ on each platform

Comment: There are no "hex values". Hexadecimal is just a textual representation of numbers, and `{ 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }` is the same as `{ 8, 1, 1, 1 }` and `{010, 01, 01, 01}`. The only way to get a number "as hex" is by creating a string with the hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want this:

```
int main(void)
{
  float f_value = 12.59;
  uint8_t *float_data = (uint8_t*)&f_value;
  int i = 0;

  while (i != 4)
    printf("%02x ", float_data[i++]);

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'd change declaration using `uint8_t `instead of `int8_t`

Answer (score 2):

What you want may be a bad idea (read comments).

Anyway, try this

```
memmove(float_data, &f_value, sizeof (float));
```

Comment: So better to declare buffer as `uint8_t float_data[sizeof(float)] = {0};`

Comment: I'd go with `unsigned char` rather than the optional `uint8_t`, but yes: that's better than OP choice.